# Munin : aggregate network traffic

Tags: debian, monitoring, munin

I have a default configuration of munin-node on 3 of my servers, and I would like to create a summary chart that displays total output bandwidth.

Here is what I have done minin.conf :

```
[example.com;aggregation]
   update no
   total_bandwidth.graph_title Aggregated bandwidth
   total_bandwidth.upload.label upload
   total_bandwidth.upload.sum \
   serv1.example.com:if_eth0:up \
   serv2.example.com:if_eth0:up \
   serv3.example.com:if_eth0:up
```

But it's not working, I only get broken images instead of graphs. In munin-graph.log :

```
[RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/www/munin/example.com/aggregation/total_bandwidth-month.png : opening '': No such file or directory
```

**EDIT :**

Following http://waste.mandragor.org/munin_tutorial/munin.html, I have tried that wich does not work better :

```
[example.com;aggregation]
   update no

   total_bandwidth.graph_title Our total bandwidth

   total_bandwidth.out.sum example.com;serv1.example.com:if_eth0:up example.com;serv2.example.com:if_eth0:up
   total_bandwidth.out.draw STACK
   total_bandwidth.out.label Out bandwidth

   total_bandwidth.in.sum example.com;serv1.example.com:if_eth0:down example.com;serv2.example.com:if_eth0:down
   total_bandwidth.in.draw STACK
   total_bandwidth.in.label In bandwidth
```

Comment: Fixed. Just replace `if_eth0:down` by `if_eth0.down`...

Comment: Would you describe your fix in an answer below and then accept that answer?  That lets the site know that this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `if_eth0:down` by `if_eth0.down`.